# On the fly functions

Tags: php, function, variables

Why can't I do this? Or am I just getting the syntax wrong?

```
$status = function() {
    switch($job['status'])
    {   case "CREATED": return "Created by <b>$creator</b> on " . date("jS \o\\f M Y",$job['ts']); break;
        case "APPROVAL": return "Pending Approval."; break;
        case "DEFERRED": return "Marked as <b>Deferred</b> by <b>$creator</b>."; break;
        case "COMPLETE": return "Marked as <b>Complete</b>."; break;
    }
}

echo $status;
```

Comment: What error do you get? What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to do it?

Comment: So you are trying to assign function to variable $status and then echo the variable, right?

Comment: @h2ooooooo `syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /var/www/vhosts/awme.net/subdomains/zephi/httpdocs/docs/hub/hub.php on line 15`

Comment: @MolecularMan yeah! i've seen it done in javascript, or jQuery, one of the two, and I was sure PHP has similar capabilities.

Comment: @Chud37, php version >= 5.3?

Comment: Aside from the fact that $job is out of scope inside your function, what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @maximkou PHP Version 5.1.6

Comment: The function(){ above the switch confuses me.

Comment: @Chud37, minimal php version for using anonymous function is 5.3

Comment: @maximkou thanks! I'll get it upgraded :)

Comment: @maximkou make it an answer and i'll accept it.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Chud37, accept Mark Baker's answer. He had already written answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) require PHP >= 5.3.0

```
$status = function($job, $creator) {
    switch($job['status'])
    {   case "CREATED": return "Created by <b>$creator</b> on " . date("jS \o\\f M Y",$job['ts']); break;
        case "APPROVAL": return "Pending Approval."; break;
        case "DEFERRED": return "Marked as <b>Deferred</b> by <b>$creator</b>."; break;
        case "COMPLETE": return "Marked as <b>Complete</b>."; break;
    }
};

echo $status($job, $creator);
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's completely correct.

Comment: syntax error, must be: `};`

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is a closure (anonymous function). But this works only in PHP >= 5.3.

The correct syntax would be:

```
$status = function($job) {
    // your switch
};

echo $status($job);

// or import $job to scope

$job = array('status' => 'CREATED');
$status = function() use($job) {
    // your switch
};

echo $status();
```

By why not just make a normal function?

```
function getStatus($job) {
    // your switch
}

echo getStatus($job);
```

Comment: That is a good point.  What is the point of anon functions then?

Comment: @Chud37 they are useful as callback parameters for example. You can pass them around like variables and do other fancy stuff with them ;) But in your case a normal function should be the best way..

Answer (score 0):

Hi
 Maybe you should have a look to [php man - variable function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/functions.anonymous.php) and [closure](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.closure.php)